Verification of a Transformed Random Variable
I am looking at the technique used to determine the pdf of a transformation of a random variable.
In Example 22.1, given $f_X(x)=3x^2,Y=X^2$, they have calculated
$$f_Y(y)=\sqrt{y}$$
which I understand.
As a verification, the page suggests integrating the pdf and verfiying that it is indeed 1.
I noticed that instead of integrating the PDF, I could also evaluate the CDF at the upper limit and get the same answer.
Here, of course, we have the correct answer.
Is it better to verify by integrating the PDF (as compared to evaluating the CDF)? In particular, if you have made a mistake, are there cases where they will give different answers?

Integrating the density over its support is one way to check that you in fact calculated the derivative of the CDF correctly; however, you are correct that evaluating the CDF at the upper limit of its support should give you $1$.  One should also check that the CDF evaluated at the lower limit of its support should give $0$.  So for instance, one would want to show that the CDF
$$F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-3x}, \quad x \ge 0$$
satisfies both
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} F_X(x) = 1$$
and
$$F_X(0) = 0.$$
However, neither of these furnish a check on calculating the density
$$f_X(x) = 3e^{-3x}, \quad x \ge 0.$$

So to be complete, I should run three checks. $F(\infty)=1,F(0)=0$ and integration gives 1? Assuming  that the random variables takes values which are positive (as in the exponential distribution that you took as an example).
